# Using a List<T> with an MVC View for only 1 item

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a viewmodel that returns a `List<T>`. I send this to several views most of which need the list because it will contain multiple objects of the `T` Type. My only problem is that I have one view that only uses one of the `T` objects. So essentially it is a list that has one object in it. Is there an easy way with out using a `foreach` loop in my view to get the one item out of the list/model? Or should I create a new viewmodel just for that view?

Comment: Use `list.First()` to sidestep an explicit loop. If there is a chance of an empty list, consider FirstOrDefault. If it is an error condition for there to be *more* than one item in the list, use Single (or SingleOrDefault).

Comment: @AnthonyPegram - You should make that an answer.

Comment: @Bobson, it's not complete enough to be an answer. If it were, this question would clearly be a duplicate because "getting the first item" has been asked often enough. I feel an answer should also address the MVC portion of the question regarding multiple viewmodels, and I do not have the experience in MVC to speak to that with any real credibility (I have *extremely limited* experience working MVVM in Silverlight).

Comment: @AnthonyPegram the complete answer is what you said, plus a simple "No" for the second question. Get the credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the Linq Extension Methods under the System.Linq namespace for that, there are several methods that allow you to select data from your list using all sorts of criteria without having to use a foreach loop.

Extension methods for IEnumerable
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx

If your view is strongly typed to the List, use the extension methods in the view.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<T> myList = //...
T myT = myList[0];
```